# Saving text selection from web/other apps by clicking on chathead (widget)

Tags: android

What I am trying to do is similar to the Diigo's "copy bubble" (a Facebook like chathead. From now on called Chathead) which basically lets the user select text in an external app/webb browser and save the selected text to the App's "note pad" activity by clicking on the Chathead:

http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/copy-bubble-clipboard-manager-fuer-android/

The flow:
1. Start a widget through the Share feature (from another app)

1. The widget shows 1 button. Clicking on the button starts the Chathead and closes the first widget.
2. The user can now select a text string, then click on the Chathead. This will do 2 things:

   a) change the text of the Chathead. So for example if the user selectet "red ball" the Chathead now will have a title visible saying "red ball".

   b) save the text string to another activity of my app (in Diigo it would be a notepad in the Diio app). This activity I have yet not created, hence no example code below.
3. When "throwing down" the chathead (just like the Facebook chat head works). The chathead is "destroyed"/closed.

What I have so far is the following:

**ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML** (adds my app to the list of apps to which the user can share content from other apps. At this point, sharing to my app will open up a normal Activity instead of the Widget. This activity shows the button that on click, will start the Chathead. To start the Chathead I have also defined a Service in the manifest)

```
<activity android:name=".NewOrExistingObjectPicker"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <service
        android:name="kowkeekowks.trackabo.Flyer"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

**NewOrExistingObjectPicker.java** (The activity that shows a button. Clicking the button will open the Chathead. ***QUESTION:*** I excluded some parts of the code that I found online since it was giving me errors and I haven't figured out what it actually does. Would be gratefull if anyone could explain the function of these lines. )

```
public class NewOrExistingObjectPicker extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_shared_content);

    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String action = intent.getAction();

  //  if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
   //     Log.d("OMG74", action);
   //     startService(new Intent(NewOrExistingObjectPicker.this, Flyer.class));
  //  }

Button launch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Log.d("OMG75", type1);
            startService(new Intent(NewOrExistingObjectPicker.this, Flyer.class));
        }
    });

    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(NewOrExistingObjectPicker.this, Flyer.class));
        }
    });

}

//  @Override
//  protected void onResume() {
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String action = intent.getAction();

//    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null)
 //   {
  //      startService(new Intent(NewOrExistingObjectPicker.this, Flyer.class));
  //  }
  //  super.onResume();
// }
}
```

**Flyer.java** (This is my Chathead. ***QUESTION***: Is it possible to have a button that the user can moved as well as clicked - i.e. be responsive to both onTouch() and onClick()? Now I have the onTouch() method attached to the WindowManager itself and I need a larger image in the background of the button in order to drag the Chathead to diferent positions.)

```
public class Flyer extends Service {
private ImageView chatHead;
private RelativeLayout parentlayout;
private WindowManager windowManager;

private RelativeLayout border;
int imageid = 1;
int nameid = 3;
Button button;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);

    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

    chatHead.setId(imageid);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    parentlayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Address");

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_imageview = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params_imageview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_name = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, imageid);
    params_name.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, imageid);


    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_button = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params_button.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    parentlayout.addView(chatHead, params_imageview);
    parentlayout.addView(button, params_button);


    windowManager.addView(parentlayout, params);
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(parentlayout, params);

    parentlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: Set the selected string as button text. Save the selected string to another Activity in my app. 

        }
    });


    try {
        parentlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(parentlayout, paramsF);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (parentlayout!= null) windowManager.removeView(parentlayout);
}
```

Many thanks for all help I can get with this!
Susanna